# Getting KeyError when trying to assign data from a dictionary into class and object in python

Tags: python, string, dictionary, variables

The file, data used

```
Austin = null|Stone Cold Austin|996003892|987045321|Ireland
    keller = null|Mathew Keller|02/05/2002|0199999999|0203140819|019607892|9801 2828 5596 0889
```

The Nested Dictionary

```
data = {'Austin': {'Full Name': 'Stone Cold Steve Austin', 'Contact Details': '996003892',  'Emergency Contact Number': '987045321', Country: 'Ireland'}}
```

The class and Object that I want to use to assign the dict data

```
class member2:
    def __init__(self, realname, phone, emergencyContact, country):
            self.realname = realname
            self.phone = phone
            self.emergencyContact = emergencyContact
            self.country = country
```

Assigning text file data into a nested dictionary

```
with open("something.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        key, values = line.strip().split(" = ") # note the space around =, to avoid trailing space in key
        values = values.split('|')
        data2 = {key: dict(zip(keys, values[1:]))}
```

#To assign data to the class **(NOT WORKING)**

```
        member2.realname = data2[values[2]]
        print(member2)

        if key == username:
            data2 = {key: dict(zip(keys, values[1:]))}
```

Output

```
member2.realname = data2[values[2]]
KeyError: 'Stone Cold Steve Austin'
```

Comment: That key ```'Stone Cold Steve Austin'``` not exist in ```data2```. Post the content of ```data2``` and ```values```

Comment: i've added the content of data2, its from a text file

Answer (score 0):

You are referring non existing key `'Stone Cold Steve Austin'`

Maybe you wish to access something like `data2[key][keys[0]]`:

```
keys = ["Full Name", "Contact Details", "Emergency Contact Number", "Country"]
with open("we.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        key, values = line.strip().split(" = ") # note the space around =, to avoid trailing space in key
        values = values.split('|')
        data2 = {key: dict(zip(keys, values[1:]))}
        print(data2[key][keys[0]])
```

Output:

```
Stone Cold Austin
Mathew Keller
```